# rewriting method with less arguments - Python

Tags: python, methods

For simplicity, I have an old class `cal1` with a method `def calculate(self,a,b,c,d,e)` and there are many places that call this method, ex: `ans=cal1.calculate(a,b,c,d,e)`.

Now I have a new class `cal2` that supposed to substitute the the old class with all methods reusing same names as`cal1` , but new one needs only fewer arguments c,d,e `def calculate(self,c,d,e)`  and not a,b.

Question: Is there a way to retrofit the new method `calculate(self,c,d,e)` to old codes without changing every single lines in the old code (ex: keeping `ans=cal.calculate(self,a,b,c,d,e)` )?
The only way I know is to change new method to take a and b as dummy, `calculate(dummy_a, dummy_b, c, d, e)`, but then for future code I'll need to carry `dummy_a`, `dummy_b`.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: `def calculate(self, *args): c, d, e = args[-3:]` perhaps?  You can then call it with either version of the parameters.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I re-praised it hope that is clearer. Basically I want to know if I can keep old codes with arguments untouched while using new method format.

Comment: @jasonharper this may work, thanks a lot! my concern is single *args is less clearer than listing all the args (or just me).

Answer (score 2):

*IF* you specify the arguments via keywords (for example `c="value", d="value", e="value"`, then it's nice an clean.

With positional arguments you can capture and unpack only the items you want.

Old calculate function signature

```
def calculate(self, a, b, c, d, e):
    ...
```

new calculate method signature (with keyword arguments):

> You can use the `**kwargs` to capture all *unnecessary* arguments here.

```
def calculate(self, c, d, e, **kwargs):
    ...
```

new calculate method signature (with positional arguments):

> You can use the `*args` to capture all arguments and pull out the ones you want.

```
def calculate(self, *args):
    *unnecessary, c, d, e = args
    ...
```

Comment: "specify the arguments via keywords." This mean old code needs to be changed since it is only positional calculate(self,a,b,c,d,e), right? I would like to know if there is a way not touching old code.

Comment: Yes, if you're not specifying all calls with keyword arguments you'll need to use `*args` and process the captured positional arguments.  _look at the (with positional arguments portion)_

Comment: Thanks! In general is single (*args) considered as less preferred practice as it looks unclear what the input arguments are, or it is fine to do so (write args in document)?